# php how to get set of values from a number that is the result of multiple numbers left-shifted and added together

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a list of known values as such:

```
const VAL1 = 1
const VAL2 = 2
const VAL3 = 3
const VAL4 = 4
const VAL5 = 5
const VAL6 = 6
```

I'm being provided a number that is the addition of 1 or more left-shifted values.  For example, I'm being provided this number:

```
98
```

How do I go about figuring out which values from my known list represent the 98?  In this example, the values would be 2 (VAL2), 5 (VAL5), and 6 (VAL6) (since 1<<2 + 1<<5 + 1<<6 = 98)

Comment: How many constant values are known?

Comment: Right now, there are 24, but there could be more added later.  But I will always know the list of possible values.

Comment: It sounds like you'll need a variable that indicates total number of constants available so that you can loop through each one. Starting at the highest and taking its bit into comparison against the target number. If it's too high, skip that number and go to the next highest number... then append bits as you go? Very enticing question I'm still trying to wrap my head around :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out by writing the following function.  This is part of a greater class, so this is just a snippet.

```
const DESTINATION_ID_USAGE_VALS = [
                        0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
                        21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,
                        39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,
                        57,58,59,60,61,62,
                      ];

public static function getDestinationIdUsageSetValues($computedMask)
{
    $current_total = $computedMask;
    $values = [];
    foreach(array_reverse(self::DESTINATION_ID_USAGE_VALS) as $possible_value) {
        $check = (1 << $possible_value);

        if($current_total == $check) {
            $values[] = $possible_value;
            $current_total = $current_total - $check;
        }
        elseif($check < $current_total) {
            $values[] = $possible_value;
            $current_total = $current_total - $check;
        }
    }

    return $values;
}
```

Example:
`$vals = getDestinationIdUsageSetValues(4194368);`

Results (array): `6,22`